# How to read cached json data with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, caching

Using last versions of jQuery 1 or 2, I have this simple code that makes a request and shows the result :

```
var url1 = "cache/1";

var callback1 = function(data, statusText, response){
    $("#result1").html("status :"+response.status);
    $("#result1").append("<p>"+JSON.stringify(data)+"</p>");
};

$(function() {

    $("#query1").on ("click", function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: url1,
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            ifModified: true,
            success:callback1
        });
    });
});
```

On the first request, I read my Json data. On the second request, I have a **304 response as expected**, and data is undefined.

How can I show data from the browser cache ?

Comment: You should get the same value in `data` as you did the first time around. Check in the Net tab of your developer tools to make sure the request you are making actually is an if-modified-since one.

Comment: Actually it's an If-None-Match and it works when I make a direct chrome GET with the url

Comment: This should be completely transparent. You get the exact same data object in a success callback that runs after a 304.

Comment: I did it again with if-modified-since and now it works perfectly. But I've changed a lot of things in the server, and I think I have put some bad ETag format. As I forced the 304 by the server, maybe the client was not able to find the correct document associated to the bad ETag. I'll work on that later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of `ifModified`

> **ifModified** (default: false)
>   Type: Boolean
>   Allow the request to be successful only if the response has changed since the last request.

Says it all, I guess. Don't use it, it does not do what you think.

```
$(function() {
    $("#query1").on("click", function(){
        $.get("cache/1").done(function (data, statusText, response) {
            $("#result1")
                .html("status :"+response.status);
                .append("<p>"+JSON.stringify(data)+"</p>");
        });
    });
});
```

Don't try to steer caching from the client. That's the server's task. Set proper caching headers and the client will work on its own.

Comment: Using if-modified-since, you can use cache=true or remove it as you wish.